# Azure AD - Users can consent to applications accessing company data on their behalf option to false

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a multi-tenant application registered as V2/converged app but it is not configured for any delegated permission that needs admin consent. I realize that if AD tenant admin set `Users can consent to applications accessing company data on their behalf option` to **false** then my application needs admin consent irrespective of configured permissions, is this understanding correct ?

Also setting this to `false` has any relation with V1 or V2/Converged app model ? As per [another blog](https://blog.peterdahl.net/2018/05/14/azure-ad-v2-apps-vs-the-brick-wall/), this seems something specific to V2.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of how this switch works is correct. When the switch is set to **No**, only users in [certain directory roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles) can grant consent to apps, in that tenant. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#understand-user-and-admin-consent):

> A tenant administrator can disable the ability for regular users to consent to applications. If this capability is disabled, admin consent is always required for the application to be used in the tenant.

This is not limited the v2 endpoint. This switch has existed since before the v2 endpoint existed, and affects all apps which have not been granted permissions already.

There is no concept of a "v1 app" registration or a "v2 app" registration, there's only a v1 endpoint, and a v2 endpoint. An app can use either endpoint.

Comment: thanks !! Logically what your are saying definitely makes sense. It should be irrespective of V1 or V2 endpoint. However, I have two apps one using v1 endpoint and other v2. I asked one of user from other tenant to login to application with v1 endpoint- he was able to login successfully while it failed with 'Admin Consent' for other app. Hence question. Also this [blog](https://blog.peterdahl.net/2018/05/14/azure-ad-v2-apps-vs-the-brick-wall/) made me feel that there might be some difference.

Comment: If the user is not a member of a role which allows consent, and user consent is disabled in the tenant, then it is likely that the permissions have already been granted for the first app (either by the user, I. Their own behalf, before user consent was disabled, or by an admin, on behalf of the entire tenant). If user consent is *allowed*, then it is likely that the second app is either requesting permissions the user isn't allowed to grant, or requires user assignment.